# Average path length: can't figure out the meaning of $\large\frac{1}{n(n - 1)}$

Tags: graph-theory, network

I am doing a few tests with the Average Path Length formula. I am testing with a directed acyclic graph. I am generating all the shortest path using a breath first walk.

Everything works fine. However, I am trying to relate what I did with the Average Path Length formula I am seeing everywhere: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_path_length), [math insight](http://mathinsight.org/network_mean_path_length_definition), etc.

All the definitions says:
$$
\bar P = \frac{1}{n \cdot (n \mathbin{-} 1)} \cdot \sum_{i \neq j}^{} d(v_{i},v_{j})
$$

All of them says that $n$ is the number of nodes in $G$.

The problem is that I am about 20 000 nodes in my graph and about 600 000 shortest paths. If I do:

$$
\bar P = \frac{1}{S} \cdot \sum_{i \neq j}^{} d(v_{i},v_{j})
$$

where $S$ is the number of shortest paths (600 000) then I get an average of 6.05 which is what I am expecting after looking at the distribution of my shortest path on an histogram.

However, if I do what I think that the formula is telling me, then I endup with doing:

$$
\bar P = \frac{1}{400000000} \cdot \sum_{i \neq j}^{} d(v_{i},v_{j})
$$

which is clearly not the average of my shortest paths.

So my question is: what is my issue with understanding this formula? I am clearly missing something in my thinking, but I don't know what.

Comment: $n(n - 1)$ is the number of pairs of distinct vertices. ($n$ choices for the source, and $n - 1$ choices for the destination.) If  your graph is connected, then the number of shortest paths between all pairs of distinct vertices should be equal to $n(n - 1)$ (assuming you pick just one shortest path when there are ties).

Comment: @Tunococ great! Well, this is what I did with my second case, right? However, am I missing something, or this is not really what I am reading from wikipedia and the other source I cited? I mean, they say where $n$ is the number of vertices in $G$. However, to me (a non mathematician) this means all the vertices (nodes) of the graph, and not the pairs of distinct vertices, no? :)

Comment: Please read carefully: $n$ is the number of vertices in $G$, while $n(n - 1)$ is the number of pairs of distinct vertices in $G$.
From what I've gathered, the only reason your $S$ is not equal to $n(n - 1)$ is probably because your graph is not connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Label all the vertices $V = \{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$. This formula is supposed to represent the average of all the shortest paths in the graph. Hence, given a node $v_1$, the average length of shortest paths emanating from $v_1$ is
$$
\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i\neq 1}d(v_1, v_i),
$$
since there are $n-1$ vertices distinct from $v_1$. Likewise, the average of shortest paths emanating from $v_k$ is
$$
\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i\neq k}d(v_k, v_i).
$$
So, if we wish to find the average of all shortest paths, we take the average of these:
$$
\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i\neq 1}d(v_1, v_i) + \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i\neq 2}d(v_2, v_i) + \cdots + \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i\neq n}d(v_n, v_i)\right)
$$
$$
=
$$
$$
\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\sum_{i\neq j}d(v_i, v_j).
$$

Comment: wonderful explanation. This and Tunococ's comments put some clarity in this.